# my subdomain share same session with master domain, how can I disable it?

Tags: php, session, drupal, subdomain, drupal-modules

I have a submain.example.com and example.com . When I set a session in example.com . I can print it out in submain.example.com. But I don't want it. What can I do to disable it?

Thank you.

Comment: maybe [session_set_cookie_params](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-cookie-params.php) could help.  look at the 3rd parameter `domain`

Answer (score 0):

You can define the valid domains for a cookie. In your case use:

```
ini_set('session.cookie_domain', $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']);
```